# NDK C++ create File in Internal storage (and read/write to it)

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have to following problem I just can't seem to fix:

I have an Android application with an Activity that passes the Path of the internal Storage to C++ via JNI:

```
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() //this passed to C++ over JNI
```

I also tried variations like:

```
getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE).toString()
```

However when arriving in C++ I have the following Code:

```
const char *path = (pathFromJava + "/someFileName.txt").c_str();
std::ofstream stream;
        try {

        stream.open(path);

        if(stream.good()) {
            stream << someDataToWrite;

            stream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (std::ios_base::failure& e) {
        std::cout << "Error no: " << strerror(errno);
    }
```

Above when trying to "open" to file we arrive at the "catch" statement and it prints: "No such file or directory".

(the std::ios_base::failure e doesn't have a meaningful message (ios failure is all it says = (e.what()))

The path passed from Java looks like: "blablub/data/package.name/files".
(seems to be fine)
and the file should usually be created when non existing by opening the stream.

I haven't found anything about required permissions for the internal storage.

May I need to create the file in Java first?
Or might the path not be the right one afterall?

Thanks for some hints in advance

- Pascal

PS: I am using the C++ code for the same app again in IOS - so writing the file stuff in Java would defeat the purpose of using C++ to have as much code as possible just once.

Comment: What's the exact path of the file you are trying to open.  The path in your post `blablub/data/package.name/files`  is a relative path (missing the intial `/`).

Comment: I think you're right I believe I somehow screwed up when converting from std::string to char Array

Comment: Ya that was it thanks :-) it somehow threw away the first /

Comment: 1) how do you get pathFromJava? 2) a while ago Android NDK did not support std::string at all. Print the paths to the log and see what you get.